# Chaning content inside a <style> tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on something and got stuck here. I was using jQuery to change text using this function:

```
$('.css').text( newval );
```

Well, there is a small twist. I wan't to change the content inside a `<style>` tag.
And it works great if I add a class to `<style class="css">` but it only works with media all. 
I wan't to do it with `@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px0)` instead. Is there any way to change a text inside that? Even if it using a different method.

---

Comment: You mean you want the content text to be different on different screen sizes?

Comment: show a bit of what you have in your style tag and what you want

Comment: I am not sure, but can't you do something like: document.querySelector('style').textContent += "@media screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) { div { color: red; }}"

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I don't think you want to use jquery for this at all. Sounds like you just need to figure out how to use media queries properly inside your css styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work, I found a solution:

```
$('body').append("<style type='text/css' id='phonecss'></style>");
$('#phonecss').html("@media only screen  and (min-device-width: 320px)  and (max-device-width: 667px) { " + newval + " }");
```

Where **newval** is the variable containing the CSS. Hope it will help others. :)

Thanks for all the help, by the way.

Regards,

Hardeep

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the css use

```
if ($(window).width() >= 1024){
     $(".your-element").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

If you are going to do that though you may as well just use media queries in your css.

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1024px){.element{background-color:yellow}}
```

If you want to change a different attribute use

```
 $( ".your-element" ).attr( "attribute", "New attribute text" );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like the following?

```
<span class="small-device-text">This is for small screens</span>
<span class="large-device-text">This is for large screens</span>
```

css-

```
.small-device-text { display: none; }
.large-device-text { display: block; }

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1024px) {
    .small-device-text { display: block; }
    .large-device-text { display: none; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate CSS styleheet rules via jQuery (or better via JavaScript) including media rules:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your style tag, add media rules and css rules in one line...
    $('style').text("@media screen and (min-width:200px) { .css { color: yellow; } }");

    // or in pure js
    document.querySelector('style').textContent += "@media screen and (min-width:400px) { .css { color: red; } }";
});
```

Example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkq1qbrL/1/).